# @login_required and is_authenticated() -- When to use which in Django?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-login, login-required

I do not see a clear distinction between using `@login_required` decorator and `is_authenticated()`: somehow, I think they perform similar checks (though not exactly).

Let say I have a `function` in my `views.py`:

```
def dosomethingNow(request):
     if request.user.is_authenticated():
         //carry out the function
     else:
          //redirect to login page
```

Same `function` with `login_required` decorator:

```
@login_required
def dosomethingNow(request):
     //carry out the function
```

Both the `function` does similar checks except that `is_authenticated()`, gives the option of redirecting to `homepage` if not `logged` in.

Any other benefits of using one over the other and places where they can't be used interchangeably?

Thanks

Comment: They are completely different things. `login_required` is applied on a method, and the user is redirected to the login page specified in the settings if anonymous user is trying to access this view. On the other hand `is_authenticated` only checks if user is logged in or not.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the way you're using them in your example code, they're essentially equivalent.

Using `user.is_aunthenticated` is more flexible (as you note, you can decide what to do if they're not--output a different template, redirect to a login form, redirect somewhere else, etc.)

However, `@login_required` is "declarative", which can be nice. You could write a script that listed all of your view functions and whether or not they had the `@login_required` decorator around them, for instance, so you had a nice report of "login-required" sections of your site. When the checking happens in your own code buried inside the function, you lose that kind of possibility.

So it's a really a question of development style: do you need the flexibility to handle this as a special case? Or does make sense to use a declarative style?

(And, if you wanted a different implementation but a declarative style--say,if you frequently wanted to redirect non-logged-in-users to the homepage, you could write your own decorator, `@homepage_if_not_auth`, and use that)